# Proof of Concentration dependence of molar conductivity

Tags: electrochemistry, concentration, ionic-compounds, conductivity

If we go by the simple electron model, Conductivity/Concentration=carrier charge*mobility and mobility is only dependent on temperature for electrons. My question is regarding strong electrolyte, I can somewhat understand the mean activity coefficient calculation using ionic strength, but still, how does the √c dependence of molar conductivity comes about in Kohlrausch Law?

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j150551a038 any way I can view the rest of this? other than the first page?

Comment: Yes, you can pay ACS money or find a library that has an electronic subscription.

Comment: can you give me some idea as to from where the √c dependece comes for strong and degree of dissociation relation for weak comes from?